# How to check/debug state of individual promises in a promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm shoving a bunch of script nodes with no `src` attribute into an array of promises that sets the `src` and then `resolve`s or `reject`s, respectively `onload` or `onerror`. All of these are called in a `Promise.all` which I `await`. The problem is, it never stops waiting. I presume some of the individual promises are resolving or rejecting, but I can't figure out how to debug which ones aren't.

```
  function loadScript (script) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // this happens for every script
      script.setAttribute("src", script.getAttribute("data-src"));
      script.onload = _ => resolve(script.src);
      script.onerror = _ => reject(script.src);
    });
  }
  
  // loadScripts : (graph, int) -> (string array) promise
  async function loadScripts(g, order = 1) {
    if (!g.has(order))
      return []
    else
      return [
        ...await Promise.all(g.get(order).map(loadScript)),
        // the script stops here after the first pass and never executes the
        // next line. It just ... awaits the previous line
        ...await loadScripts(g, order + 1)
      ]
  }
```

I got to this point by setting breakpoints in Chrome devtools and stepping, but I'm not sure, once we're sitting and awaiting, how to check the state of the individual promises, to see which ones are resolving and which are still pending.

Comment: Log the value of `g.get(order).map(loadScript)` before passing it to `Promise.all`, then inspect its element in your debugger.

Comment: I would wait to call `setAttribute` until after setting `onload` and `onerror`. I'd also tend to prefer `script.src = ...` over `script.setAttribute("src", ...)`

Comment: those are `script` onload, not `document` onload. If I didn't `setAttribute` they would never `onload`. Why do you prefer `script.src`?